# Easiest way to hit a URL every x minutes

Tags: java, php, cron

My plan is to hit an url (GET - rest) (ex: http://myserver.com/job ) every x minutes, I want to use something that could be free on the long run like a small programm running on heroku cloud.

Can I build something like that in php or java ? (both languages are supported on heroku and I have some familiarity with both)

I've tried in java so far but I don't think the multi-threading nature of it works because it gives me an error if I make any "request" logic inside a loop.

Sorry to ask such a broad question but from my search I havent found any good ideas for this problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have some tags missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** Use IFRAME for your URL and in Javascript use setTimeout() to iterate.

**DETAILED ANSWER:** Modify the following source as per your needs.

(!!! https://www.disney.com is ok but some URLs may not accept IFRAME requests.)

### IN .HTML / .JSP:

```
  <head>
      <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" url="init.js"/>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()">
      <form id="form1">
         <iframe id="w_iframe" src="https://www.disney.com" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute">
           <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
         </iframe>
      </form>
  </body>
```

### init.js:

```
 function init() {
    var w_src = "https://www.disney.com";
    document.getElementById("w_iframe").src = w_src;

    setTimeout("init()", 60000);    //60,000 milliseconds
 }
```

Comment: Does this only work if I open the webpage?

Comment: Actually it should refresh itself every x milliseconds. Please give it a try.